# Перегрузка оператора [] в C++

Tags: c++

```
class risc { // singleton
protected:
    static unsigned long registers[8];

public:
    unsigned long operator [](int i) const    {return registers[i];}
    unsigned long & operator [](int i) {return registers[i];}
};
```

Когда будет вызываться `unsigned long operator [](int i) const`, а когда `unsigned long & operator [](int i) {return registers[i];}`? И необходим ли вообще метод `unsigned long operator [](int i) const`?

Comment: "И необходим ли вообще метод unsigned long operator [](int i) const?" - на этот вопрос Вы должны ответить сами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто. `const`-метод будет вызываться для `const`-объекта. Соответственно, не-`const`-метод — для не-`const`-объекта.

Пример:

```
void test(risc& r, const risc& cr)
{
    r[0]++; // вызывает unsigned long & operator []
            // значение можно менять
    cr[0] = 5; // вызывает unsigned long operator [],
               // присваивание rvalue, не компилируется
}
```

[Официальный C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-overloading) (перевёл и адаптировал):

> `const`-перегрузка — это ситуация, когда у вас есть метод для чтения и для модификации с одним и тем же именем и тем же количеством/топом параметров. Они отличаются только тем, что метод для чтения содержит модификатор `const`.
>
> Наиболее частый случай использования — оператор индексирования `[]`. [...] Если вы создаёте свой класс с таким оператором, обычно **операторы индексирования ходят парами**.
>
> Константный оператор индексирования возвращает ссылку на `const`-результат (или, как у вас, rvalue), таким образом компилятор предотвращает непреднамеренное изменение вашего объекта. Неконстантный оператор возвращает неконстантную ссылку, таким образом позволяя вызывающей стороне (и компилятору) модифицировать ваш объект.
>
> Когда пользователь применяет перегруженный оператор индексирования, компилятор выбирает перегрузку в зависимости от константности объекта. Если ваш объект — `risc r` или `risc& r`, компилятор выберет неконстантный метод, и у пользователя будет неконстантная ссылка на `long`.
>
> Но если у пользователя есть лишь `const risc r` или `const risc& r`, тогда вызов будет скомпилирован в вызов константного оператора, и пользователь получит rvalue (или `const`-ссылку, в зависимости от того, как определён ваш оператор).

Иными словами: компилятор выбирает не-`const`-оператор, если может. Если не может (например, у вас `const`-объект, а значит, не-`const`-методы вызывать нельзя), выбирается `const`-версия.